# angular-ui-tree tree inside tree doesn't create empty-tree-placeholder

Tags: angular-ui-tree

Hi I need to create a tree which represents some categories from GroupA these categories can be 4 level deep.

This is a very simple task, but additionaly each of a category has counterparts in GroupB, GroupA aggregates GroupB , so let's say CategoryX from GroupA can contain 3 categories from GroupB.

This is something like category mapping.
All data is in one **json**.

In order to reflect this relationship I came up with an idea to nest tree (GroupB) inside each row of parent tree (GroupA)

Something like this:

```
ui-tree                             --> Root of tree
  ui-tree-nodes                     --> Container of nodes
    ui-tree-node                    --> One of the node of a tree
      ui-tree-handle
      ui-tree
         ui-tree-nodes
           ui-tree-node
             ui-tree-handle
```

Everything renders well, but when inner ui-tree is empty it does not appear empty-tree-placeholder, and I can't drop new nodes anymore.

Do you know how to solve this problem?